# how to create python parallel sockets in asyncio and transport_base class?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-asyncio, parallels, transport

I used asyncio for my non-stop server in python and implemented 
connection_made , connection_lost , data_received 
funtions in my ServerClientProtocol

I used this class first beacause of using multiple times repeatedly sending data to socket class socket 
got closed and program exited

and second becuase I thought its async and have parallel answering multiple coming sockets in same time,
but it's not.

how should I use that in one async thread and parallel answering socket?

this is my code:

```
    class ServerClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):    
        def connection_made(self,transport):
            self.transport = transport

        def connection_lost(self,exc):
            pass

        def data_received(self, data):
            server.server(self,data)

    def main(*args):    
        loop = get_event_loop()        
        coro = loop.create_server(ServerClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 50008)    
        srv = loop.run_until_complete(coro)    
        loop.run_forever()    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Still no answer???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server.server()` might be blocking the other connections.  If this is a long-running call, try using [`asyncio.start_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server) (example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams)) instead, and call `server.server()` using [`await loop.run_in_executor(None, server.server, data)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor)

Comment: I wrote some code, but its still sequential, not async. `coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 50008,loop=loop) srv = loop.run_until_complete(coro)        
    loop.run_forever() @asyncio.coroutine
def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = yield from reader.read(500)
    message = data.decode(encoding='utf-8')            
    
    `

Comment: `    nameindex=('name="calculator2"' in message)
    if nameindex:
        time.sleep(5)
        writer.write("Content-Length: 1\r\n\r\n2".encode())
        yield from writer.drain()
    else:
        writer.write("Content-Length: 1\r\n\r\n1".encode())
        yield from writer.drain()
   
   

    print("Close the client socket")
    writer.close()`   @udi

Comment: these 2 comments are my new code for testing async and syn. and saw that again its syn

Comment: Please start a new question (or edit your question above) instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: Thanks.I did that with this code and it worked: yield from asyncio.sleep(5)